# What's the period of $\{2x\}$

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

What is period of the function :
$f(x)=\{2x\}$,where $\{\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$ .

Comment: $f(1/3) = f[(1/3) + (1/2)].$  Also, $f(1/7) = f[(1/7) + (1/2)].$

Comment: So it's period is (1/2)

Comment: What do you think?  Try proving that assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand, for every $x$ we have
$$ f\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\left\{2\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right\}=\{2x+1\}=\{2x\}=f(x) $$
so the period is at most $\frac{1}{2}$.
On the other hand, for every $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$ we have $0<2\epsilon<1$ and
$$ f(\epsilon)=\{2\epsilon\}=2\epsilon\ne 0 = f(0)$$ so the period cannot be $\epsilon$ and is exactly $\frac{1}{2}$.